# Merging times between start and stop events in R

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets where one dataset contains a datetime variable (`dataA`) and another dataset contains start and stop times (`dataB`).  I want to take all datetimes between the start and stop times.  I came up with a simple solution, but it takes over 3 hours for a dataset with around a million observations.  Can someone please provide a faster solution?  Below is an example with my solution; it works well for small sample sizes, but reducing `secBetwMeas` greatly increases the computation time (setting `secBetwMeas=5` takes almost 40s) .

```
secBetwMeas <- 5*60
dataA <- data.frame(id=c(rep("A",length(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 01:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("2014-01-02 04:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by=secBetwMeas))),
                         rep("B",length(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 04:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("2014-06-02 05:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by=secBetwMeas)))),
                    dataDtTm=c(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 01:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                 as.POSIXct("2014-01-02 04:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by=secBetwMeas),
                               seq(as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 04:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                   as.POSIXct("2014-06-02 05:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by=secBetwMeas)))
dataB <- data.frame(id=rep(c("A","B"),each=2),
                    startDtTm=c(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 01:10:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2014-01-02 03:05:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 04:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 22:10:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
                    endDtTm=c(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 08:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                              as.POSIXct("2014-01-02 07:05:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                              as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 08:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                              as.POSIXct("2014-06-02 04:05:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))


### Trying to optimize this solution: ###
dataA$endDtTm <- dataA$startDtTm <- as.POSIXct(NA)
for(i in 1:NROW(dataA)){
  index <- (dataA$id[i]==dataB$id & dataA$dataDtTm[i] >= dataB$startDtTm & dataA$dataDtTm[i] <= dataB$endDtTm)
  stopifnot(sum(index)==0 || sum(index)==1)
  if(any(index)){
    dataA$startDtTm[i] <- dataB$startDtTm[index]
    dataA$endDtTm[i] <- dataB$endDtTm[index]
  }
}
dataA <- na.omit(dataA)
head(dataA)  #This is the dataset I want to see
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
dataC <- merge(dataA,dataB, by="id")
dataC[dataC$dataDtTm >= dataC$startDtTm & dataC$dataDtTm <= dataC$endDtTm,]
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't think of that